# How to do a build and cli from same src python package..?

Tags: python, build, installation

Here I am having a repo is like,

```
- Makefile    
- src
     - mypackge
         - __init__.py
         - __main__.py
         - Usageclass.py
     - setup.py
```

Currently I am using makefile for running `setup.py`. My setup.py is like,

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = 'mypackage',
    version = '0.1.0',
    packages = ['mypackage'],
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'mycmd= mypackage.__main__:main'
        ]
    })
```

I am doing this for building this package,

```
python setup.py build --build-base=../build install --install-scripts=../build/bin
```

I don't how to make a CLI with a build directory structure. I just want to make executable CLI inside the build dir with a bin/lib structure from the src shown below like this.

```
-Makefile
-src
 .... (already shown above)
-build
   - bin
       -mycmd
   - lib
      -mypackage (or) mypackage.egg
```

I would like execute mycli command `mycmd` from inside `bin` directory which is connected with `lib` directory package/egg file. I don't know where to correct or how to make it easily ?